# JSONP Post Proxy

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am writing a fairly basic web app that integrates with the Twitter API. I am requesting the auth token Twitter require with jQuery and AJAX but I am violating the asynchronous cross site request policy or whatever it is.

I would use JSONP but the Twitter API requires a POST. I have read I should use an itermediate proxy. I have no idea what that involves and can't find any resources? I can write in PHP.

Can anyone explain what a proxy page is?

**UPDATE**

Following reading the accepted answer below I wrote a PHP proxy script, this is what I came up with and got working:

```
    <?php

    class proxy {

        public $serviceURL;
        public $postString;
        public $headers;
        public $response;

        public function __construct($url) {  
            $this->serviceURL = $url;
            $this->postStringify($_POST);
        }

        private function postStringify($postArray) {
            $ps = '';
            foreach($postArray as $key => $value) { 
                $ps .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
            }
            rtrim($ps, '&');
            $this->postString = $ps;    
        }

        private function isCurlInstalled() {
            return (in_array('curl', get_loaded_extensions())) ? true : false;
        }

        public function makeRequest() {
            if ($this->isCurlInstalled()) {
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->serviceURL);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);            
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->postString);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);
                $this->response = curl_exec($ch);
                if ($this->response === false) $this->response = curl_error($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
            } else {
                $this->response = 'Need to install Curl!';
            }

            return $this->response;

        }

        public function debug() {
            var_dump($this->response);
        }

    }

?>
```

and in another file which the AJAX request calls:

```
    <?php

    include ('proxy.php');

    ini_set('display_errors',1); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $consumerKey = 'myKEY!';
    $consumerSecret = 'mySecret!';
    $bearerTokenCredentials = $consumerKey . ':' . $consumerSecret;
    $base64TokenCredentials = base64_encode($bearerTokenCredentials);

    $authProxy = new proxy('https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token/');
    $authProxy->headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization: Basic ' . $base64TokenCredentials,
    );

    $response = $authProxy->makeRequest();
    if (is_null($response)) $authProxy->debug(); else echo $response;

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proxy script will simply take your POST data and relay it on to Twitter.

In your client-side code, instead of using the URL for Twitter, you will use something like `yourProxyScript.php`.  In that proxy script, you will take everything from `$_POST`, along with any other data you need, and [POST it to the Twitter API URL using cURL](http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post).